# Fill Combobox from database

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have an error with a combobox

My code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
try
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHARKAWY;Initial Catalog=Booking;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456");
    string query = "select FleetName, FleetID from fleets";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader drd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (drd.Read())
    {
         cmbTripName.Items.Add(drd["FleetName"].ToString());
         cmbTripName.ValueMember = drd["FleetID"].ToString();
         cmbTripName.DisplayMember = drd["FleetName"].ToString();
    }
}
catch
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error ");
}
```

The data is presented in the combobox, but when you **change the selection valuemember the displaymember does not change.**

It's working now but when I click the button to show the data

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = cmbTripName.DisplayMember;
    label2.Text = cmbTripName.ValueMember;
}
```

This is displayed:

FleetName
FleetID

It does not display the value

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will have to completely re-write your code. **[DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx)** and **[ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx)** point to columnNames! Furthermore you should really use a `using block` - so the connection gets *disposed* (and *closed*) after query execution.

Instead of using a **dataReader** to access the values I choosed a **dataTable** and bound it as dataSource onto the comboBox.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHARKAWY;Initial Catalog=Booking;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456"))
{
    try
    {
        string query = "select FleetName, FleetID from fleets";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Fleet");
        cmbTripName.DisplayMember =  "FleetName";
        cmbTripName.ValueMember = "FleetID";
        cmbTripName.DataSource = ds.Tables["Fleet"];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // write exception info to log or anything else
        MessageBox.Show("Error occured!");
    }               
}
```

Using a *dataTable* may be a **little bit slower** than a *dataReader* but I *do not have to create my own class*. If you really **have to/want to** make use of a *DataReader* you may choose **@Nattrass approach**. In any case you should write a **[using block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**!

**EDIT**

If you want to get the current Value of the combobox try this

```
private void cmbTripName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbTripName.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        DataRowView drv = cmbTripName.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        Debug.WriteLine("Item: " + drv.Row["FleetName"].ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("Value: " + drv.Row["FleetID"].ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("Value: " + cmbTripName.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: it's work now but i need to insert ValueMember and displaymember to label

`            label1.Text = cmbTripName.DisplayMember;
            label2.Text = cmbTripName.ValueMember;`

Comment: THE RESULT: SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWVIEW NOT THE NAMES

Comment: @AhmedSharkawy did you find the solution to "SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWVIEW" because I am still stuck in it !

Answer (score 8):

To use the `Combobox` in the way you intend, you could pass in an object to the `cmbTripName.Items.Add` method.

That object should have `FleetID` and `FleetName` properties:

```
while (drd.Read())
{
    cmbTripName.Items.Add(new Fleet(drd["FleetID"].ToString(), drd["FleetName"].ToString()));
}
cmbTripName.ValueMember = "FleetId";
cmbTripName.DisplayMember = "FleetName";
```

The `Fleet` Class:

```
class Fleet
{
     public Fleet(string fleetId, string fleetName)
     {
           FleetId = fleetId;
           FleetName = fleetName
     }
     public string FleetId {get;set;}
     public string FleetName {get;set;}
}
```

Or, You could probably do away with the need for a `Fleet` class completely by using an anonymous type...

```
while (drd.Read())
{
    cmbTripName.Items.Add(new {FleetId = drd["FleetID"].ToString(), FleetName = drd["FleetName"].ToString()});
}
cmbTripName.ValueMember = "FleetId";
cmbTripName.DisplayMember = "FleetName";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void Fillcombobox()
{

    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID From Employees",con);
    Sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (Sdr.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Sdr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
           comboID.Items.Add( Sdr.GetString(i));

        }
    }
    Sdr.Close();
    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump your code in an answer. Try to at least provide a brief explanation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please improve your code-only answer by adding some explanation (and maybe some formatting). That way you help the asker noticably more. And you also do not want to give the impression that you are providing a free code writing service, do you?

Answer (score 1):

Out side the loop, set following.

```
cmbTripName.ValueMember = "FleetID"
cmbTripName.DisplayMember = "FleetName"
```

Comment: Should set column names for those properties. You have set the data values. That is the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TOM-PC\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=xyz") ;
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select customerid,contactname from customers", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader;

            reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("customerid", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("contactname", typeof(string));
            dt.Load(reader);

            comboBox1.ValueMember = "customerid";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "contactname";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

            conn.Close();
```

Comment: Some explanation behind how the code works would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void StudentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
         string q = @"SELECT [BatchID] FROM [Batch]"; //BatchID column name of Batch table
         SqlDataReader reader = DB.Query(q);

         while (reader.Read())
         {
             cbsb.Items.Add(reader["BatchID"].ToString()); //cbsb is the combobox name
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "SELECT column_name FROM table_name";      //query the database
SqlCommand queryStatus = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
sqlDataReader reader = queryStatus.ExecuteReader();                               
            
while (reader.Read())   //loop reader and fill the combobox
{
ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader["column_name"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. ```
   using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
   ```
2. Write that:

   ```
   MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("datasource=172.16.2.104;port=3306;server=localhost;database=DB_Name;uid=root;password=DB_Password;sslmode=none;charset=utf8;");
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

   var query2 = "SELECT `salary` FROM `employees_db` ";
   using (var command2 = new MySqlCommand(query2, con))
   {
       using (var reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (reader2.Read())
           {
               combox.Text  = reader2.GetString("salary");
           }
       }
   }
   ```