# populate with item and assign value to comboBox from database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve the records from database and assign them to comboBox. I only did it but when I try to select anyone from the comboBox, I always get the value of the last record in the comboBox. Please help me. Here is my code.

```
        command = new SqlCommand("Select supplier_id, supplier_name from tbl_supplier", MySqlConnection);
        m_dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (m_dr.Read())
        {
            comboBoxSupplier.Items.Add(m_dr["supplier_name"].ToString());

            comboBoxSupplier.ValueMember = (m_dr["supplier_id"].ToString());

            comboBoxSupplier.DisplayMember = (m_dr["supplier_name"].ToString());
        }
        m_dr.Close();
```

Comment: Side note: instead of calling `m_dr.Close()` enclose both `command` and `m_dr` into *using*: `using (var m_dr = ...) {...}`

Comment: use datatable or IList datasource to populate your combobox.. DataReader will not work

Answer (score 0):

The answer from the linked question: [Fill Combobox from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494634/fill-combobox-from-database)

cmbTripName.ValueMember = "supplier_id";
cmbTripName.DisplayMember = "supplier_name";

point to the columns outside of the loop. (I tried this and it worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

int count = 0;
foreach (datarow row in dt)
{
    count += 1;
    comboBoxSupplier.Items.Add(dt[count]["supplier_name"].ToString());   
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow. It's always better to explain what the code does and how it addresses the question. This helps future users.