# how to access emp_id and name from ComboBox in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, combobox

i have no idea about to access emp_id and emp_name from database into combo Box of dot net-C# window application.
my job is that i want show EPM Name into comoBox but search that profile using that emp_id that is related to emp_name. note that emp_id will not show only Emp name will show... just like combo box of HTML... where we store

```
<option value="$row[emp_id]">$row[emp_name]</option>
```

like this way i want in c#.... 
how can it possible...

Answer (score 1):

```
MySQLconnection con =  new MySqlconnection(connection.mySql());
MySqlcommand cmd = MySqlCommand("Select emp_id ,emp_name from Table where emp_name='Sandeep' order by emp_id ASC",con);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "emp_id"; 
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "emp_name";
```

Load your database table in a dataset "ds" and use the above code.

Comment: modified my code according to your requirement. Please check

Comment: This is my Sample code ... i did not copy .. all is same like this.. bro please help....

Comment: MySQLconnection con =  new MySqlconnection(connection.mySql());
  MySqlcommand cmd;

  MySqlDataReader dr;

  if(con.State.ToString() == "Closed")
  con.open();

  cmd = MySqlCommand("Select Emp_id ,Emp_name from Table where emp_name='Sandeep' order by emp_id ASC",con);
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  if(dr.hasRow)
  {
  while(dr.Read())
  {
  combBox1.items.Add(dr["emp_name"].ToString());
  }
  dr.disposed();
  cmd.disposed();
  }

Comment: Check my modified answer

Comment: You can use datareader to fill combobox but since you need name and value both for each element you need a separate class for that. Check second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494634/fill-combobox-from-database