# Returning a List from my database class to a form in c#

Tags: c#

In a form i want to have a combobox filled With names that are in my database. 
Everything directly to do with the database happens in my dedicated database class. I want the answers that come up from my sql query to go to the form and display in my combo box.

This is what i have so far:

```
public string categories()
    {
        InitializeDatabase();
        connection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT Name FROM Categories";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                catList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        return catList;
    }
```

As my discovered i cannot simply return a list too bad. 
but im really in a ditch on how it should go to work. The results need to be displayed in the combobox thats on my other form where there isnt really any code yet

```
    public partial class AddImage : Form
{
    DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector();
    public AddImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        databaseConnector.categories();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494634/fill-combobox-from-database

Comment: What is the type of "catList" here.. It is a list of String? Why can't you load categories from the form where the combobox is located? The link share by OldProgrammer explains it about how to bind Combobox.

Comment: See my two form project at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Im given an error: cannot implicitly convert type 'System.collections.Generic.List<string> to string   
So i changed the method to a list string. But the combobox only says (collection) there isnt actually anything in there

Comment: Assume you're using Winforms?  You haven't posted any code relating to a ComboBox, form databinding, but here's how to do it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms

Answer (score 2):

You can totally return a List - it's just that you've declared your return type as string:

```
public string Categories()
{
```

should be

```
public List<string> Categories()
{
    var catList = new List<string>();
```

(Also, since it's not clear from your code what the scope of catList is, I've declared it as a local variable in Categories)

Comment: With the use of a breakpoint ive discovered that the list is getting returned andits getting there for the biggest part but its simply not being put in the combo box. is anything wrong with this

            comboBox1.Items.Add(databaseConnector.categories());

Comment: You're trying to add an entire List as a single item.  You need to bind the list, or add each category as an item.  Is this WinForms or WebForms?  I haven't done either in 8 years, but here's what looks like the answer for WinForms:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms