# How to populate a combobox with query that contains user input?

Tags: c#, mysql

My SQL query is not working. The query is something like this:

```
QueryString = SELECT material FROM tbl1 WHERE vendor = UserInputVar;
```

This query would run after the UserInputVar was made by the user from selecting a value in a combobox(say, combobox1). What this query does is that the results fetched by this query will populate another combobox(say, combobox2).

I tried to find the solution online but nothing works on my current problem. I tried to do it on my own by trying the following:

- Use MySqlDataAdapter together with MySqlCommandBuilder, then use the adapter to fill a data table and that data table would be the datasource
- Put QueryString and connect_DBstring in a MySqlCommand constructor and use a variable instance of MySqlCommand. Then, use adapter and commandbuilder to fill the datasource of second combobox.

Any suggestions and links would help. I really don't know what to do since I usually use MySqlDataReader for SELECT statements and MySqlDataAdapter for INSERT statements. I haven't had an experience using SELECT with MySqlDataAdapter before

Comment: Rather than asking for off site links, why not post your code so someone can help you.  Also, there are gobs of articles and samples on the DbDataAdapter at MSDN

Comment: Please post your code so that people can understand the problem and help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use user input in SQL statement since it creates possibility to make [SQL injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

   ```
       using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(con))
       {
           try
           {
               connection.Open();
               using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
               {
                   command.CommandText = "SELECT material FROM tbl1 WHERE vendor=@vendor"
                  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor", UserInputVar);
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   connection.Close();
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
       }
   ```
2. As for populating combobox from SQL query take a look at the following post:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/12495086/1099716

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved the problem. It turns out my way of parameterized query is wrong but I finally corrected it. Instead of using MySqlCommand parameters, I used MySqlDataAdapter parameters instead. I never knew about it at first but thankfully I know now.