# Fill Combobox with list of data from mysql c#

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I have this method

```
public List<Trgovina> getAllStores()
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("dbConn")))
    {
        return connection.Query<Trgovina>("TrgovineViewAll", null,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
            )
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

It gets all the store(s) information from the database. The method it called on startup

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Trgovina> stores = new List<Trgovina>();
    stores = da.getAllStores();
    comboxStoreNames.ItemsSource = stores;
}
```

stores is filled with data. Though the data is not in the format I need. It just shows `{Project_Budget.Engine.Trgovina}`. The information I need is inside that. How can I take that data from there in a string format so I can show it in a combobox?

Comment: why aren't you use datasource and DisplayMember and ValueMember ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494634/fill-combobox-from-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either override `ToString`

```
public override string ToString() => ThePropertyOrExpressionToBeDisplayed;
```

or, if you are using databinding, set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the ComboBox. `DisplayMember` is the property you want to display. `ValueMember` is typically an Id or key property. You can access the latter through `SelectedValue` while you can get the whole object through `SelectedItem` and its index through `SelectedIndex`.

Note that in your case, the ComboBox was using `ToString`; however, as the default implementation inherited from `System.Object` is to return the type name, you did not get an adequate display.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the combobox, which allows you to bind the property you want.