# I want to insert value from another table column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have 2 table like this,

tbl_motor

```
motor_id     motor_types
--------------------------
1            audi
2            Ferrari
```

tbl_employee

```
employee_id   employee_name   motor_id
--------------------------------------
1             jack            2
2             john            1
```

But I have problem. I used combo_box on my register.
My combo box query is `select motor_types from tbl_motor`.

How to insert new value to `tbl_employee` which is my combo box is string
emmmm I mean parse that string to int.

Comment: 'emmmm I mean parse that string to int..' - ?

Comment: That should be a question about the part in the program logic. Make sure your combobox uses the object with the ID and not just the texts.

Comment: As @juergend says, populate the combobox with both the ids and text.
For example: `<option value=1>audi</option>` When submiting to the server, you'd have the id to reference when inserting to tbl_employee.

Comment: I just followed the steps from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqpp3hXBZVI , Im just can't implement it(object id) into mysql.

Comment: related: [Populating a ComboBox using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2417960/9260725) and [How to bind a List to a ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/600869/9260725)

Answer (score 1):

A `ComboBox` can contain objects of any type. You should avoid setting adding texts as items. Add your motors instead.

You propably have a class like this:

```cs
class Motor
{
    public int MotorId { get; set; }
    public string MotorType { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() // Important to override. This will be used to show the text in the combobox
    {
        return this.MotorType;
    }
}
```

And this is how you add `Motors` and read the SelectedItem:

```
// This is your Array which you got from your DB
Motor[] motors = new Motor[]
{
    new Motor() { MotorId = 1, MotorType = "Audi" },
    new Motor() { MotorId = 2, MotorType = "Ferrari" },
};

// We clear old items and add the motors:
this.comboBox1.Items.Clear();
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(motors);

// Select something for demonstration
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;

// Read the selected item out of the combobox
Motor selectedMotor = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem as Motor; 

// Let's have a look what we got
MessageBox.Show(selectedMotor.MotorId + ": " + selectedMotor.MotorType);
```