# Timer to Update DataContext in MVVM-WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a text log File which i parse every 10 seconds to display it values on the WPF-Application, I am trying to use MVVM for the first time in WPF. The problem i am facing is I am unable to refresh the DataContext with the timer.
The format of the text file is

log.txt

> UserID|RP1|MS9|1.25
>
> UserID|RP5|MS7|1.03

Code for the Application is given below

Code for Model-Class

```
 public class UserModel
 {
     public string userID{get; set;}
     public string RP{get; set;}
     public string MS{get; set;}
     public string Rate{get; set;}
 }
```

Code for ModelView-Class

```
 public class AppModelView
 {
     private ObservableCollection<UserModel> _userList;
     DispatcherTimer LogTimer;
    
     public AppModelView()
     {
          _userList = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
          LogTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
          LogTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);  
          
          LogTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
          {
             foreach(DataRow row in LogManager.Record) //LogManager is class which parse the txt file and assign value into a DataTable Record
                   _userList.add(new UserModel
                   {
                       userID= row[0].toString();
                       RP = row[1].toString();
                       MS = row[2].toString();
                       rate = row[3].toString();

                    });
           };
           LogTimer.Start();
     }

     public ObservableCollection<UserModel> UserList
     {
          get { return _userList; }
          set { _userList = value;
                 NotifyPropertyChanged("UserList");}
     }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
 }
```

MainWindows.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="MonitoringSystem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Monitoring Server"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="768" WindowState="Maximized" >

  <Grid>
     <DockPanel>
            <Label Content="User Monitored" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
            <ListView Name="lstRpt" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="UserID"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding userID}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="RP" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RP}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="MS"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MS}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Rate"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Rate}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</Windows>
```

MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppViewModel VM = new AppViewModel();
        this.DataContext = VM;
     }
 }
```

Now if I remove the DispatcherTimer it display the values which were parse for the first time and display it , but with timer it cannot display any values.
Your Guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: unable to refresh the DataContext - What does this mean? The code seems alright. The ListView will show changes for every 10 seconds, if THERE IS ANY CHANGE.

Comment: @XAMLLover I cannot get any values on the form, if i remove the dispatchertimer then it parse the values for first time and display on the form

Comment: @WiXXeY: show the code, which populates new `UserModel` properties. And you don't want to change the data context, you want to update list of users, don't you? Also, why is `UserList` made read-write? Who should assign it, instead of `AppModelView` instance itself?

Comment: @Dennis The user properties are populated perfectly I have debug it many times, but I will make edit in my code

Comment: @Dennis Yap I want to update the list of users. and no one will assign values to it apart from AppmodelView

Comment: you add the item to the private which dont have notification _userList instead of UserList.

Comment: @AminBudianto Didnt got what are you pointing at, kindly elaborate

Comment: you will need to add the new UserModel to UserList instead of _userList. because UserList is the one implement NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @AminBudianto: what a nonsense. `ItemsSource` updates `Items` collection, when it receives `CollectionChanged` event from underlying collection. There's no need to change *collection* (don't confuse with *content* of collection) to update items, if the collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, as `ObservableCollection` does. Moreover, `UserList` should be readonly.

Comment: @WiXXeY: your code looks OK. Does `LogManager.Record` contains anything, when the timer fires?

Comment: thanx i have figured it out by following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470101/liststring-inotifypropertychanged-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suspect is happening is that your `UserModel` is getting added to the collection before its properties have been set, and because your `UserModel` has no INPC the view never updates once they are set.

Try changing your code to:

```
LogTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    foreach(DataRow row in LogManager.Record) //LogManager is class which parse the txt file and assign value into a DataTable Record
    {
        var userModel = new UserModel
        {
            userID= row[0].toString();
            RP = row[1].toString();
            MS = row[2].toString();
            rate = row[3].toString();
        };

        _userList.Add(userModel);
    };

    LogTimer.Start();
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Correction needed only in ViewModel

```
public class AppModelView
    {
        private ObservableCollection<UserModel> _userList;
        DispatcherTimer LogTimer;

        public AppModelView()
        {
            _userList = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
            LogTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            LogTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);

            LogTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                 new Action(
                     delegate()
                     {
                         UserList.Add(new UserModel
                         {
                             userID = "test"
                         });
                     }
                 )
                );
            };
            LogTimer.Start();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<UserModel> UserList
        {
            get { return _userList; }
            set
            {
                _userList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UserList");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why to run new delegate using dispatcher in `DispatcherTimer`'s callback, which, in turn, also uses dispatcher to fire?

Comment: Hi haven't check. It will work without dispatcher also. Issue is with _userList. Use UserList collection instead