# Winforms datagridview - variable number of columns - INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, inotifypropertychanged

Let's say I have two classes:

```
public class Hour : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Value
    {
        // ...
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}

public class Day
{
    public int Number
    {
        // ...
    }
    public BindingList<Hour> Hours { get; set; } = new BindingList<Hour>();

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
```

I want to show those data in the datagridview - first column is day number, and then there are columns for each hour. I've used this solution:

[WinForms DataGridView - databind to an object with a list property (variable number of columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716092/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-an-object-with-a-list-property-variable-num)

Everything is working fine until I change the value programatically - I can change the number of day and the value is refreshed automatically inside the datagridview but when I change hour, datagridview is not refreshed and the new value is refreshed when I click on the specific row. I change it like this:

```
days[0].Number = 55;

days[0].Hours[0].Value = 55;
```

Could someone tell me if it's even possible what I am trying to achieve and if so, how can my goal be achieved.

I've tried to look inside PropertyDescriptor and datagridview to see, how is it working internally but I am still stuck on this problem.

EDIT:

This is my current solution:

```
public class Hour : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            SetField(ref _value, value, "Value");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

    public class Day : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _number;

        public int Number
        {
            get => _number;
            set
            {
                SetField(ref _number, value, "Number");
            }
        }

        public BindingList<Hour> Hours { get; set; } = new BindingList<Hour>();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
}

    class DayList : BindingList<Day>, ITypedList
    {
        public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            var origProps = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Day));
            List<PropertyDescriptor> newProps = new List<PropertyDescriptor>(origProps.Count);
            PropertyDescriptor doThisLast = null;
            PropertyDescriptor doThisFirst = null;
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in origProps)
            {
                if (prop.Name == "Hours") doThisLast = prop;
                else newProps.Add(prop);
            }
            if (doThisLast != null)
            {
                var min = this.Min(f => f.Hours.Min(h => h.Value));
                var max = this.Max(f => f.Hours.Max(h => h.Value));

                if (max > 0)
                {
                    Type propType = typeof(Hour);

                    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++)
                    {
                        var item = new ListItemDescriptor(doThisLast, (int)(i - min), i, propType);
                        newProps.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(newProps.ToArray());
        }

        public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    class ListItemDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        private static readonly Attribute[] nix = new Attribute[0];
        private readonly PropertyDescriptor tail;
        private readonly Type type;
        private readonly int index;
        public ListItemDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor tail, int index, int value, Type type) : base(tail.Name + "[" + value + "]", nix)
        {
            this.tail = tail;
            this.type = type;
            this.index = index;
        }
        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            IList list = tail.GetValue(component) as IList;
            return (list == null || list.Count <= index) ? 0 : ((Hour)list[index]).Value;
        }
        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get { return type; }
        }
        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }
        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return tail.ComponentType; }
        }
        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then I create DayList and set is as datasource for datagridview.

This is the result:

[image: datagridview]

As I said when I change the number, everything is ok (datagridview cell is refreshed) "days[0].Number = 55;" but when I set the value of an hour "days[0].Hours[0].Value = 55;", the cell is refreshed when I click on the specific row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470101/liststring-inotifypropertychanged-event

Comment: I edited my question. BTW I tried ObservableCollection and still couldn't make it work.

Comment: `public Day() {
    Hours.CollectionChanged += Hours_CollectionChanged;
}

private void Hours_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged("Hours");
}` . ObservableCollection<Hour> Hours.

Comment: Thats exactly what I've tried. But it does not solve the problem.

Comment: `public Day() {
    Hours.ListChanged += Hours_ListChanged; ;
    
}

private void Hours_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged("Value");
}` OnPropertChanged has to have the Value string in it that way datagrid will update the column. Bindinglist

Comment: I _want_ to answer this with an implementation for `ListItemDescriptor` that would fix the binding. I've reproduced this and `Days[0].Number = 55` works and `Days[0].Hours[0].Value = 99` also works. What makes it tricky is the mention of **variable number of columns** because there might be two separate issues here. I'll be happy to post what I've got if you think it would move the chains.

Comment: First of all, I'd like to say thank you lork6, I just can't vote for your comment (I guess because of my low reputation here)... I would also appreciate, if you would show us your solution @IV if it's gonna work and lork6 won't post his solution as a separate answer I would mark your solution as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public Day() {
     Hours.ListChanged += Hours_ListChanged;
 }  
 private void Hours_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {     
     OnPropertyChanged("Value"); 
 }
```

OnPropertChanged has to have the Value string in it that way DataGridView will update the column.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the go-ahead in your comment, here's a snippet that partially answers your question. A good place to start might be to finish out the implementation of your `ListItemDescriptor` class so that it maps column names like "Hour[00]" to the array object `Day.Hour[0]` in both read and write directions.

[image: poc screenshot]

It could look something like this:

```cs
class ListItemDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    public ListItemDescriptor(string name) : base(name, new Attribute[0]) { }
    public override Type ComponentType => typeof(Day);
    public override bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public override Type PropertyType => typeof(int);
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) => true;
    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        if(component is Day day)
        {
            switch (Name)
            {
                case nameof(Day.Number): 
                    day.Number = default; 
                    break;
                default:
                    var index =
                        Convert.ToInt32(_getIndex.Match(Name).Groups[1].Value);
                    day.Hours[index].Value = default; 
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    Regex _getIndex = new Regex(@"\[(\d+)\]");
    public override object? GetValue(object? component)
    {
        if(component is Day day)
        {
            switch (Name)
            {
                case nameof(Day.Number): return day.Number;
                default:
                    var index = 
                        Convert.ToInt32(_getIndex.Match(Name).Groups[1].Value);
                    return day.Hours[index].Value;
            }
        }
        return default;
    }
    public override void SetValue(object? component, object? value)
    {
        if(component is Day day)
        {
            switch (Name)
            {
                case nameof(Day.Number): day.Number = Convert.ToInt32(value); break;
                default:
                    var index =
                        Convert.ToInt32(_getIndex.Match(Name).Groups[1].Value);
                    day.Hours[index].Value = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) => true;
}
```

I posted a clone link to my POC where I tried the two test cases  but it will take more work if columns are going to come and go. One thing I am  wondering is, since there are always 24 hours in a day, why not let DGV have a complete set of columns and modify the *visibility* of the columns instead? Do you have reasons other than making columns hidden or shown where you want to dynamically add and remove them?

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/property-descriptor-binding.git). That said, when I have had the need to be more flexible (my users can make arbitrarily named columns at runtime) what I found made it a lot easier was to use `DataGridView` in [VirtualMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode?view=windowsdesktop-8.0).

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you for your answer. As I said, if lork6 is going to post his solution, which solved my problem I have to mark his answer as the most helpful. I don't have enough reputation to mark your answer as useful but when I will have 15 rep, I will come back to give it to you because you deserve it.