# How do I let the user match items from two lists together?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two lists. The first contains names (string) the second contains filters (object).

What I want is to supply a UI to the user, in order to allow them to match a name with a filter.

A filter can be matched to many names, a name must be matched to exactly one filter.

How do I do this? I believe there are no ready-made controls for the job.

**Example:**

User should be able to do this:

- name1 -> filterA
- name2 -> filterA
- name3 -> filterB

Comment: Are you using `ListBox` or `ListView` ??

Comment: I don't mind using any of them! Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: And how are the filters are defined? are they a reference to an object or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most natural way I can think of would be to supply a ListView with all the names on the left, and a ComboBox on the right that holds the filters.

This would also ensure the user can only select one filter.

Comment: This was also my first thought. Have you found any examples on how to do this using datasources? I really do not want to map everything and get the values back from the ui and add them in classes and so on..

Comment: It's been a while since I did any winforms development... however there are plenty of questions on the subject here on SO. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using `ListView` you can use `Tag` & `Name` propety of `ListViewItem` to supply some hidden data (atleast from user) and compare those properties of each listview item.

You can try something like this (it is not tested and written on the fly :P) I am still not sure if I got your question. so forgive me!!

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ListViewItem item1;

    int i = 1;
    while (i < 6)
    {
        item1 = new ListViewItem();
        item1.Text = "Item" + i.ToString();
        item1.Tag = new List<string>();
        listView1.Items.Add(item1);

        i++;
    }

    i = 1;
    while (i < 6)
    {
        item1 = new ListViewItem();
        item1.Text = "Filter" + i.ToString();
        listView2.Items.Add(item1);

        i++;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> temp = (List<string>)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;

    temp.Add(listView2.SelectedItems[0].Text);

    listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag = temp;
 }
```

Comment: how is user going to do the matching?

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample data so people can get a better idea of what you are looking for? Obviously the matching should be done with your code :P User just sees a string on the screen!

Comment: added an example in my question