# populating texbox with combobox info

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to populate 2 different textboxes with the objects properties everytime the combobox selected item changes. I have the following code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {            
        Domicilio[] domicilios = new Domicilio[]{
            new Domicilio{Calle="balbin",Numero=469},
            new Domicilio{Calle="palacios",Numero=589},
            new Domicilio{Calle="rep arg",Numero=748},
            new Domicilio{Calle="escalada",Numero=562}
        };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (var d in domicilios)
            {
                cbbDatoDomicilio.Items.Add(d);
                cbbDatoDomicilio.DisplayMember = "Calle";   
            }    
        }    
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);                        
        }    
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // missing code here!
            txtCalle.Text = d.Calle;
            txtNumero.Text = d.Numero.ToString();                
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way of populating them. The problem with the code is that the variable `d` is out of scope and that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to *define your variable d* within your method and **assign the selectedItem** of **comboBox1**

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Domicilio d = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Domicilio;
      if (d!=null)
      {
        txtCalle.Text = d.Calle;
        txtNumero.Text = d.Numero.ToString();
      }
 }
```

On the other hand you may consider using a **bindingSource** and accessing it's BindingSource.Current member!! (have a look at [**How to: Bind a List**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms) or [DataBinding example](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html) or MSDN [How to: Bind a Windows Forms ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex.aspx)