# C# ComboBox List<object> ==> Show always the same object.name (multiple time)

Tags: c#, list, object, combobox

I just want my ComboBox to show me the

FullName of objects in List(Curator),

but it show me the same "object.FullName" multiple times :-(

-

Basically, it work cause it show me the FullName of ONE of the Curator,

and the good amount of times,

but it show me the same ONE !

```
public partial class SGIArt : Form
{
     public static Gallery gal = new Gallery(); // from a dll i made

     List<Curator> curList = new List<Curator>();

     public SGIArt()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboCur.DataSource = curList;
        comboCur.ValueMember = null;
        comboCur.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        UpdateCurList();
    }
    public void UpdateCurList()
    {
        curList.Clear();
        foreach (Curator cur in gal.GetCurList())    
                  // from the same dll : Curators curatorsList = new Curators();
        {
            curList.Add(cur);
        }
    }
    private void comboCur_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboCur.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            //show info in textBox (that work fine)
        }
    }
}
```

Curator class  :

```
public class Curator : Person
{

    private int id;
    private double commission;
    const double commRate = 0.25;
    private int assignedArtists = 0;

    public int CuratorID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }
    ...

    public Curator()
    {
    }

    public Curator(string First, string Last, int curID)
        : base(First, Last) // from : public abstract class Person
    {
        id = curID;
        commission = 0;
        assignedArtists = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You might be looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms) answer.

I do not see the FullName member in your code snippet. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
List<Curator> curList = new List<Curator>();

public SGIArt()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  comboCur.DataSource = datasource;
  comboCur.ValueMember = null;
  comboCur.DisplayMember = "FullName";
  UpdateCurList();
}
List<string> datasource()
{
  List<string> datasource = new List<string>();
  foreach(Curator curator in  curList)
  {
    datasource.Add(curator.FullName)//this assume FullName is an accesible member of the Curator class and is a string.
  }
  return datasource;
}
```

Comment: i got the same problem :-(  (so i can just use obj to list my comboBox)

Answer (score 0):

The comboBox shows you `object.FullName`, because this is what you are telling it. The `curList` is empty at the time when you bind it.

You can update your list before using it:

```
public SGIArt()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UpdateCurList();
    comboCur.DataSource = curList;
    comboCur.ValueMember = null;
    comboCur.DisplayMember = "FullName";
}
```