# Need to 'BindingList' a member of a struct to a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, bindinglist

Good Morning:

I have a situation where I have this struct:

```
private struct EmployeeInfo
{
    public string LastName;
    public string FirstName;
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address;
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
}

private BindingList<EmployeeInfo> ei = new BindingList<EmployeeInfo>();
```

I have a ComboBox on the screen that needs to be populated only by the 'FullName' member so I can get the index of the List to access the other information in it.

Is this possible?  Originally I had the members with their own separate BindingList (i.e. not in a struct), but it didn't seem right to me.

I tried a few different things (which didn't work), and I did a search here, but nothing seemed close enough to what I was doing.

Thank you, as always. :)
Robert

Comment: What platform? WinForms? Wpf? Web (Dropdown)?

Comment: I apologize - WinForms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to bind a list to a combobox? (Winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this, perhaps in form constructor :

```
comboBox.ValueMember = "EmployeeID";
comboBox.DisplayMember = "FullName";
comboBox.DataSource = ei;
```

Then setup a selection change handler :

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    var employeeId = (int)cmb.SelectedValue;
    // use the value to get more info...  
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to...  but it won't let me yet...  (I have to wait 5 minutes it says)