# SelectedValue for a combobox returns an unexpected value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ComboBox which is populated on form load. I get the data from the database in the form of a dataset and use the following to populate the combobox.

```
checkBox4_combo.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true,"Work_Location");
checkBox4_combo.DisplayMember = "Work_Location";
checkBox4_combo.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

But, when I try accessing the items of this combobox, it returns an undesirable output.
 I have tried the following:
Method 1:

```
object ob = checkBox4_combo.Items[0];
MessageBox.Show(ob.ToString());
//Returns "System.Data.DataRowView"
```

Method 2:

```
checkBox4_combo.SelectedIndex = 1;
object ob = checkBox4_combo.SelectedItem;
//OR
object ob = checkBox4_combo.SelectedValue;
MessageBox.Show(ob.ToString());
//Returns "System.Data.DataRowView"
```

Method 3:

```
checkBox4_combo.SelectedIndex = 1;
object ob = checkBox4_combo.SelectedText;
MessageBox.Show(ob.ToString());
//Returns <blank>
```

But, if I use:

```
checkBox4_combo.SelectedIndex = 1;
object ob = checkBox4_combo.Text;
MessageBox.Show(ob.ToString());
```

I will get the desired output but that means that the selected text gets changed. So essentially, I would not want to use this, and methods 2 & 3.

**Now, besides asking for a solution, I want to understand why the output is either null or "System.Data.DataRowView". Is there something in the way that I am binding the data to the combobox which is a problem? Or is this how it works and I should stick to my last solution?**

Comment: try to set the DataMember-Property of your Combobox to the Column you want to see in your MessageBox.

Comment: Are the values in the datatable expected to change or will they remain constant? Because in the second situation, you should convert the given column into a list and make it the datasource (lists, unlikely datatables, are the ideal types for being a combobox datasource and that's why they will automatically deliver the behaviour you want).

Comment: @MarcoForberg Sorry but comboboxes in winforms don't have such a property.

Comment: @varocarbas Not exactly, but they have something similar - ValueMember. It works as DataMember I assume

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not directly/in the most logical way. If you want to get the displayed values right away with something like `checkBox4_combo.SelectedValue` you would have to rely on a "more appealing" datasource, like a list.

Comment: For example: `checkBox4_combo.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true,"Work_Location").AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Work_Location"]).ToList();`

Comment: @varocarbas I took your advice and did some research and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms). As per that, I still would be binding it and would have to use a valuemember, much like what Marco suggested together with user2946329's code. It works.

Comment: There are many alternatives (even you might rely on a binding approach different than the DataSource property). But the best way to keep things simple and working fine with a combobox is DataSource + List.

Comment: @varocarbas Okay, yes. You're right. This works. The example that you stated works, and it is reduced code.

Comment: @varocarbas you're right. actually i meant ValueMember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `checkBox4_combo.SelectedItem` to `DataRowView` like this:

```
var ob = (DataRowView)checkBox4_combo.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(ob[0].ToString());//Change ob[0] to each column index that you want
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing what you see (controlled by the [DisplayMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property) with what you get (controlled by the [ValueMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) property). When you use `DataTable` as data source and don't specify `ValueMember`, it's normal to get `DataRowView` object from `SelectedValue` property. `Items` property elements are also of type `DataRowView`.

In order to get the **display text** of a combo box item, you can use [GetItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this

```
int index = ...;
var item = comboBox.Items[index];
var text = comboBox.GetItemText(item);
```