# How to display comboBox value instead displaying name of objects

Tags: c#, winforms, list, foreach, combobox

About 3 hours I am trying to solve this issue. My combo box display to me name of object instead a value for example: A

[image]

This is my class:

```
namespace Supermarket
{
    public class WhareHouseTable
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double cost { get; set; }
        public string offer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<WhareHouseTable> product = new List<WhareHouseTable>();
    product.Add(new WhareHouseTable { name = "A", cost = 0.63, offer = "Buy 2 for the price of 1" });
    product.Add(new WhareHouseTable { name = "B", cost = 0.20 });
    product.Add(new WhareHouseTable { name = "C", cost = 0.74, offer = "Buy 2; get B half price" });
    product.Add(new WhareHouseTable { name = "D", cost = 0.11 });
    product.Add(new WhareHouseTable { name = "E", cost = 0.50, offer = "Buy 3 for the price of 2" });
    product.Add(new WhareHouseTable { name = "F", cost = 0.40 });

    comboBox2.DataSource = product;
    comboBox2.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

    source.DataSource = product;

    foreach (var selected in product)
    {
        comboBox2.Text = selected.name;
        itemCostLabel.Text = selected.cost.ToString();
        offerLabel.Text = selected.offer;
    }
}
```

In foreach I am trying to get all products and represent them in comboBox and in labels.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: check this ilnk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify one of the properties in the bound source as its `DisplayMember` which is going to be displayed and the same or another property as its `ValueMember` which you can access through `selectedItem.Value`

```
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "Name";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override toString() method of the  class like  this:

```
public override String toString(){
    return name;
}
```