# i want to update the quantity on a list box c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

how to update e specific value on a list..
for example when i click a button it adds the product on the list

> name: coffe    ||     quantity:1      ||   Price:2$

and when i click angain the same product the quantity increases by 1
i used this code but it doesnt change the number of the quantity.

```
private BindingList<recipt> Lista2 = new BindingList<recipt>();
private void addtolist(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button b = (Button)sender;
    Product p = (Product)b.Tag;
    recipt fat = new recipt ()
    {
        Name= p.Name,
        quantity= 1,
        price = p.Cmimi
    };
    bool found = false;
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var pr in Lista2)
        {
            if (pr.Name== p.Name)
            {
                pr.quantity= pr.quantity+ 1;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            fat.tot= fat.quantity* fat.price;
            fat.Nr_bill = Convert.ToInt32(txtNrbill.Text);
            Lista2.Add(fat);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        fat.tot= fat.quantity* fat.price;
        fat.Nr_bill = Convert.ToInt32(txtNrbill.Text);
        Lista2.Add(fat);


    }
    fat.tot= fat.quantity* fat.price;
    fat.Nr_bill = Convert.ToInt32(txtNrbill.Text);
    Lista2.Add(fat);
    pe.Faturs.Add(fat);
    pe.SaveChanges();

    Total = Total + (int)fat.price;
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to bind a list to a combobox? (Winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms)  ListBox binds the same way.

Comment: i dont want to bind..i want to update a value of quantity every time i add the same product..

Comment: If the quantity is updated in the object (use a Watch to check), it is probably a lack of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface with your recipt class. BindingList tell the control to update when you add or remove object. But it doesn't do anything when an object is changed.

Comment: so i need to change the BindingList to a list?

Comment: @MarcoGuignard - `BindingList` will notify control about changes inside object if object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Fabio - Of course. But the object (recipt class here) have to implement this interface ! B.Shehu - No using the BindingList is correct here, with a list your control (the listbox) would not update when you add (or remove) a objet. The question here is to know if it is an binding update issue (INotifyPropertyChanged not implemented most of time) or an issue with you addtolist() Sub (your code does not step in the right place).

Comment: @Fabio - but how to find the total of all receipt in this way ?

Comment: @Fabio - and then  add to database every product in this recipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating values in ListBox automatically you need set `BindingList` of receipts to the `ListBox.DataSource` and make `Receipt` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class Receipt : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }
    public decimal Price { get; }
    public string BillNumber { get; private set; }
    public decimal Total => Price * Quantity;
    public string Info => $"{nameof(Name)}: {Name} || {nameof(Quantity)}: {Quantity} || {nameof(Price)}: {Price:C} || {nameof(Total)}: {Total:C}";

    public Receipt(string name, decimal price, string billNumber)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        BillNumber = billNumber;
        Quantity = 1;
    }

    public void AddOne()
    {
        Quantity += 1;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Info));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in the form

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    private readonly BindingList<Receipt> _Receipts;

    public YourForm()
    {
        _Receipts = new BindingList<Receipt>();

        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Info";
        listBox1.DataSource = _Receipts;        
    }

    private void AddToList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button) sender;
        var product = (Product) button.Tag;
        var receiptInfo = _Receipts.FirstOrDefault(receipt => receipt.Name.Equals(product.Name));
        if (receiptInfo == null)
        {
            receiptInfo = new Receipt(product.Name, product.Cmimi, txtNrbill.Text);
            _Receipts.Add(receiptInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            receiptInfo.AddOne();
        }
    }
}
```