# Insert list in combobox

Tags: c#, list, foreach, combobox

Im Trying to get my list in to a combobox by using the following code

```
        List<string> Regions = new List<string>();
        Regions.Add("EU");
        Regions.Add("NA");
        Regions.Add("KR");
        Combobox1.DataSource = Regions;
```

This didn't work when I started the program. I also tried using a foreach like this

```
        foreach (var Region in Regions)
        {
            Combobox1.Items.Add(Region);
        }
```

Does someone now how to do this,

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to bind a list to a combobox? (Winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms)

Comment: Thanks for commenting I made a mistake in the placement, sorry im a noob

Comment: Glad to hear you found the cause! Stepping through your code and observing the values of variables really helps in cases like these :) If you're not familiar with stepping through your code, check out [this Microsoft guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx).