# I'm facing a problem, where it is taking so much time to display a list thad is added to a database

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-code

Iam currently working on a book management project and I'm using SQL Server from Visual Studio. I have a Book Category table in the database and I'm trying to place it in a combobox.

This the code - I don't see anything wrong with it but the categories are taking so long to be visible in the combobox.

Also the list is repetitive, is it maybe because of the `while` Loop? If so is there any way to fix it?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\malek\source\repos\BookStore\BookStore\BOOKDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                scmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                scmd.CommandText = "SELECT CATEGORY FROM BOOKCAT";
                var rd = scmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    List.Add(Convert.ToString(rd[0]));
                }
                int i = 0;
                while (i < List.LongCount())
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(List[i]);
                    i = i + 1;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception EX)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

What did I miss?

NOTE: I am not getting any errors!!

Comment: What kind of combo box?  Winforms?  WPF?  Webforms?  Maui?  Xamarin?  Other?

Comment: In any case, this can almost certainly be done in a much simpler way, generally with a Data Binding.

Comment: Well its Winforms. How do you mean with Data Binding?

Comment: Side note: Your `while` loop is a strange choice. A `for` loop would be much more idiomatic for what you're doing.

Comment: `LongCount` iterates through the collection every time. It can't be optimized because the optimizations used by `Count()` rely on `int` properties. That's what's bogging it down. You have an `O(n^2)` operation. Do you really think you might have more than 2.4 *billion* items in this list? And since you're declaring your counter `i` as `int`, it'll overflow if you do and end up being an infinite loop.

Comment: [How to bind a list to a combo box in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/600869/102937)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you've posted, it looks like you're loading the categories from the database in the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged) event of `comboBox1`.

So, every time you choose a new item from `comboBox1` you're executing this code; you're going to the database and loading everything from the `BOOKCAT` table and you're putting those items into `List` and `comboBox1`. That is why you're seeing duplicated categories. It's probably also why it takes so long for a category to be visible in the `ComboBox`.

You probably don't want to load the `ComboBox` items from the database every time the selected index changes, so you should do that somewhere else. For example, you could do it in the `Form`'s constructor, or in the ['Load' event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load).

Answer (score 1):

> How do you mean with data binding?

Like this

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM BOOKCAT ORDER BY CATEGORY"
  @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\malek\source\repos\BookStore\BookStore\BOOKDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
categoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "CATEGORY";
categoryComboBox.ValueMember = "CATEGORY";
categoryComboBox.DataSource = dt;
```

And when you want the thing the user selected:

```
 var cat = categoryComboBox.SelectedValue as string;
```

Simple eh?

It gets even easier if you use a strongly typed dataset; for that you just add a new DataSet type file to your project (must use net framework not net core/5+), drag your db into your dataset, add a query to the category TableAdapter that gets the distinct categories (like above) then open the data sources window, change Category to a combo and tag it onto the form. No code to write; vs will write it all